# Tensorflow Model inference with multiple cameras

Tags: tensorflow

i trained a tensorflow model (SSD MOBILE NET V2) and export it for using to detection on webcam but now i want to use the model to detect from the stream of multiple cameras not one camera

Comment: More information would be useful.
Which programming language are you using f.e.?
What did you try already?

Comment: @abdoalii37 Did you find any solution for it?